# setTimeout and QuickTabs

Tags: 6, javascript, blocks

I'm using [QuickTabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) with a couple of views to show some content within tabs. This works fine.

Now, I want my tabs to automatically cycle. Basically, [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/264299) sums up what I want to do.

The thing is, it partially works. I have two tabs, and it cycles to the second tab, but immediately goes back to the first. I have enough time to see it blinking, but that's it.

Here is the slightly modified code (original code does the same, I just find it nicer):

```
var rotateSpeed = 5000;
setTimeout(function featureRotate() {
  var active_tab = $('ul.quicktabs-style-basic').find('li.active')
  var next_tab = active_tab.next()
  if(next_tab.length){
    next_tab.find('a').trigger('click')
  }
  else {
    /* remove the following line if you don't want it to cycle */
    $('ul.quicktabs-style-basic').find('li.first a').trigger('click')
  }
  setTimeout(featureRotate, rotateSpeed);
}, rotateSpeed);
```

Debugging it, it looks like the `setTimeout` function works when it goes through the `else` statement, but not when it goes through the `if` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the problem was just plain old Javascript.

The bug made it look like the setTimeout had no delay parameter, which defaults to `0`.

After looking more at it, the `rotateSpeed` variable was not available in the block scope of the `featureRotate` function, but in its closure.

So I replaced the following:

```
// In the featureRotate function
setTimeout(featureRotate, rotateSpeed)
```

With:

```
// In the featureRotate function
setTimeout(featureRotate, this.rotateSpeed) // Look at this magic :-)
```

And it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setInterval()` insead:

```
function featureRotate() {
  var active_tab = $('ul.quicktabs-style-basic').find('li.active')
  var next_tab = active_tab.next()
  if(next_tab.length){
    next_tab.find('a').trigger('click')
  }
  else {
    /* remove the following line if you don't want it to cycle */
    $('ul.quicktabs-style-basic').find('li.first a').trigger('click')
  }
}

var rotateSpeed = 5000;
setInterval("featureRotate()", rotateSpeed);
```

Comment: Not working. Exact same problem.

Comment: Btw, your code doesn't work :). You have to use `setInterval(featureRotate, rotateSpeed)`.

Comment: I just wrote something from memory, never test it. But I'm glad I gave a starting point :)

Comment: It didn't :p Out of the box, your code doesn't work. I had to change it to make it work, with the bug. See my answer to see what was wrong :-). Also, I wouldn't recommend [setInterval](http://wallofscribbles.com/2011/setinterval-the-sneaky-basterd-child-of-javascript/) ;o)

Comment: Dude, I know it didn't work. I just said it was a starting point for you...

Comment: And I said it wasn't a starting point... See "with the bug" in my comment up there.

Comment: Whatever. Starting point means something does that doesn't work but puts you on the right track and can continue from there. I just wanted to help... next time I'll stay aside.